# Cannot redeclare css style

Tags: html, css

I want to re-declare css class style, but it's not working and I don't know why....

Maybe some description:
If user hover button, button move 1px down. But if I use button version 2 - class: button-v2, I want to disable this effect, but it doesn't works :/

Do you have any idea, how to solve it? Thank you very much :)

EDIT: When I run the snippet, it works as I want so, here is also link to real example: [real example](http://dev.inovestudio.com/new/#)

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.button.button-big {
  padding: 12px 18px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
.button:hover {
  top: 1px;
}
.button:active {
  top: 3px;
}
.button.button-v2:hover {
  top: 0px;
}
.button.button-v2:active {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button button-pink button-big">Some string</a>
<a href="#" class="button button-blue button-v2 button-big">Some string</a>
```

Comment: It's working fine as you have it currently: http://jsfiddle.net/7nmpnmt8/

Comment: What is your question? The code behaves as expected to me...

Comment: Yeah, I see, so I edit my question and add real example. Button-v2 is the latest button - the blue one in the footer.

Comment: When I go to the page and open page source it has a different class than the one mentioned in your question: button button-blue button-v2 button-big

Comment: The reason it's not working on your live site is because you have the anchor tag wrapped in a div with the class `button` which is causing the div to shift down 1px on hover.

Comment: CalebB yeah, it has. I removed in my question some classes, because they weren't neccessary for my question.
@APAD1 aaaah, thank you so much! I didn't noticed it :/

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us :)